# Apply and group in the Pandas python

Tags: python, group-by, apply

I have a DataFrame like:

```
df:

        cell            COMBINATION_ID     PREDICTION   SYNERGY_SCORE
0       BT-549            ADAM17.AKT    2.188390       7.398240
1      CAL-148            ADAM17.AKT   10.030628      12.686340
2        HCC38            ADAM17.AKT    9.217011      -4.351590
3      DU-4475           ADAM17.FGFR   -2.130943     -14.398730
4      HCC1187           ADAM17.FGFR   -1.103040      -6.400371
5        HCC70           ADAM17.FGFR   -2.076458     -14.909000
6     Hs-578-T           ADAM17.FGFR    3.831822      -7.859544
```

I want to groupby the COMBINATION_ID and also get the correlation of the PREDICTION and SYNERGY_SCORE

result will be like this:

```
ADAM17.AKT   cor([2.188390,10.030628,9.217011],[7.398240,12.686340,-4.351590] 
ADAM17.FGFR  cor([-2.130943,-1.103040, -2.076458 ,3.831822],[-14.398730,-6.400371,-14.909000,-7.859544]
```

I can use:

```
df2 = df.groupby('COMBINATION_ID').apply(f)
```

but I don't know how to define `def f()`:

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [pandas' corr()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html) with a defined function, assuming you have the `scipy` package installed with pandas. You can specify the method between: *pearson* (default), *kendall*, and *spearman*:

```
def f(row):    
    row['CORRELATION'] = row['PREDICTION'].corr(row['SYNERGY_SCORE'], method='spearman')
    return row

df2 = df.groupby('COMBINATION_ID').apply(f)
```

You can check new column above with actual figures:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import spearmanr    

# ADAM17.AKT 
print(spearmanr([2.188390,10.030628,9.217011],
                [7.398240,12.686340,-4.351590]))
# ADAM17.FGFR 
print(spearmanr([-2.130943,-1.103040, -2.076458 ,3.831822],
                [-14.398730,-6.400371,-14.909000,-7.859544]))
```